# The process cannot access the file 'C:\Photo.jpg' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#-4.0, file-upload, file-io, image-uploading

i m trying to resize the uploaded image and save it in a particular location by replacing the existing file. But this gives me an error saying "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Photo.jpg' because it is being used by another process."

here is my code.

```
private void llblChangePlayerPicture_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            ofdPlayerPicture.Reset();
                ofdPlayerPicture.Filter = "JPEG(*.jpeg,*.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.jpg|Bitmap (*.bmp)| *.bmp |PNGs(*.png)|*.png";
                ofdPlayerPicture.ShowDialog();
                Image newImage;
                if (ofdPlayerPicture.FileName != "")
                {
                    pboPlayerPicture.Image = null;
                    pboPlayerPicture.ImageLocation = null;
                    newImage = Resize(Image.FromFile(ofdPlayerPicture.FileName), new Size(250, 100));
                    SaveJpeg(Program.playerImagePath + regNo + "\\Photo1.jpg", newImage, 100);
               }
```

here is my save image

```
 public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image img, int quality)
            {
                EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
                ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
                EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
                System.IO.MemoryStream mss = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                img.Save(mss, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
                byte[] matriz = mss.ToArray();
                fs.Write(matriz, 0, matriz.Length);

                mss.Close();
                fs.Close();
                mss.Dispose();
                fs.Dispose();
            }
```

Incase i want to delete the Photo.jpg using File.Delete function, it gives me the same issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Dispose all the objects, and the picture boxes in which the Image is used. Whether it is used in same control or different control. Recreate the picture box control in the main control every time the image is changed. Works perfectly fine for me.

Hope this is useful.

Happy coding